# Sql ER Diagram: product with parents relations

Tags: sql, entity-relationship

Hello I have the following situation:

I have a product instance table that is nothing more than a product already assigned to a department and employee.

Well, but I have the following business logic: the product can be an equipment, or a component, that is, a product can have children.

thinking how a computer case is a device that has patrimony_code, and has child products (components) such as:
motherboard,
memoirs,
vga

etc etc
and all of these components are connected to the equipment.

I arrived at this with less table:

[image]

But I encountered some problems:
my components would not need departament_id, as they do not belong to the department but to the equipment that there belongs to the department.

[image]

So I came to this modeling, but I don't know if it is a good thing to do this relationship, could someone help me if there is a more clean / solid solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

if I have understood your description correctly, only a piece of equipment can be assigned directly to a department, not the individual components that make up the piece of equipment?

Assuming this is the case then I suggest you split this problem into 2 separate tasks as they are, in reality, unrelated and trying to treat them as a single model is causing confusion:

1. Model the relationship between an instance of a piece of equipment and a department
2. Model the hierarchy of components (and their instances) that make up a piece of equipment

Once you have these two models you can then relate them if you need to but logically they are separate and you can change one without affecting the other

Hope this helps?

**UPDATE 1**
(in response to your questions)

You construct 1 sub-model that covers your Equipment entity and the Component entity (plus any other relevant entities) that describe how your products are modelled.

Your construct a second sub-model that describes how equipment is assigned to a department.

The only entity that would be (necessarily) common to the 2 sub-models is the Equipment entity; though, obviously, you can display both sub-models on the same diagram if that is required - even though they are logically separate (apart from the one common entity: Equipment)

Comment: not a department for having one or many pieces of equipment, and the equipment is a product that can have one or more components in its composition

Comment: this 2. I didn't understand could you give me an example how it would look? in what case did you say the second modeling option that I put on the topic seems correct?

Comment: In other words, an example of equipment: it is a computer, whose composition is one or more products.

Comment: can u give me one simple example about this submodel? i dont understand how work.